# Why does Convert.ToString( (sbyte)-128, 2) prepend 1's?

Tags: c#, tostring

My understanding is that there is no ToString overload that takes a sbyte and it is getting explicitly cast as short. But where are these leading 1's coming from?

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", Convert.ToString((sbyte)-128, 2));

>1111111110000000
```

Thanks,
Gybe

Comment: Can you explain why you expected something different? What result did you expect?

Comment: What I had expected was simply 1000 0000, but sblom's explanation makes perfect sense. I'll be sure to add more detail in future.

Comment: You converted the sbyte -128 to short and you expected to get -32768, which seems like a strange thing to expect. What I would expect is what you got, namely, -128 stored in a short.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this after so long, only just saw the response.  But what I had expected was simply the binary representation of -128, that is what I had typed? I did not understand the need to fill the full 16bits but obviously if all 16 bits are to be used to represent -128 then the prepended 1's make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is completely right.

The 1s are caused by a thing called "[sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension)". It's a side effect of the way [2s complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) binary arithmetic works.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually calling the overload of Convert.ToString defined as:

```
Convert.ToString(short value, int base)
```

A signed byte uses the first bit as the sign - you are first implicitly converting it to a short which because of the way binary is stored keeps prepending 1's to maintain negativity. (i.e. 10000000 in sbyte form is -128 in binary).

Comment: Sorry - a bit slow today: realised you already mentioned all that information in the question!